# ASP.NET: 1.1 to 2.0 upgrade

Tags: asp.net

what are some things i should be aware of before i begin this project? i've notice a few differences between this 1.1 site and our 2.0 sites: i noticed that every code behind file has a "Web Form Designer Generated Code" region which i'm guessing i won't need to transfer over to the 2.0 site.(?) There's also a "sitename".dll file in the bin folder which i was told is also a 1.1 thing and that dll file won't need to be transferred over to the 2.0 site.(?) at this [**-LINK-**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274994/upgrading-asp-net-from-version-1-1-to-2-0-any-gotchas), the second answer mentions that my new 2.0 site should be created as a Web Application Project and not a Web Site project - does this apply to all 1.1 to 2.0 upgrades and should i consider doing this?

i would appreciate any advice at all on a 1.1 to 2.0 upgrade that you have. i should also mention that i am not allowed to upgrade to either 3.5 or 4.0 - it has to be 2.0. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

2.0 brought a new project type for websites which, in the simplest terms, does not produce a dll for the website like 1.1 projects would.  There was a patch released that supported the 'older' project type if you really hated the new website project (which I did).

To be honest I did not have that much trouble converting my sites over to 2.0 way back when it came out.  Visual studio automatically converted my projects and I only had a few bugs to work out to be honest.

Try using the automatic upgrade (simply open the project in visual studio 2005 after you install 2.0) and see if you have any issues.

Comment: He won't have to worry about "web site projects" assuming he installs at least Visual Studio 2005 SP1. He can just ignore them.

Comment: is the new project type included in the service pack?  Thats nice!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to install the latest service packs and be sure to test, test, test. .NET 2.0 added some fixes that amount to breaking changes in .NET 1.1. You may run into them especially in the area of XML processing in general, and XML Serialization in particular.

Note also that .NET 3.5 is nothing more than .NET 2.0 plus some additional assemblies that your code does not use. There is no good reason to not upgrade to .NET 3.5 SP1.

There *are* potential reasons to not upgrade to .NET 4.0, though not very many.