# IIS 5, Migration from .net 1.1 to .net 2.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-2.0, .net-1.1, iis-5

My client is using IIS 5.0 and .NET 1.1 on their Windows Server which is reaaally old!

Just wondering what are the risks of upgrading the server from .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0? and would IIS 5.0 support .NET 2.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading ASP.NET from version 1.1 to 2.0 - Any Gotchas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274994/upgrading-asp-net-from-version-1-1-to-2-0-any-gotchas)

Comment: I think the addition of IIS 5 as a factor means this is still a unique question.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, this is *not supported*. The reason it is not supported is that IIS 5 runs on Windows Server 2000, and [Microsoft no longer supports Windows Server 2000](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2010/01/14/windows-2000-server-approaching-end-of-life.aspx)... at all. New security patches are not released for Windows 2000, and have not been for a few years. In other words, any security issues found since July of 2010 are still open and exploitable on that system, no matter how much work you've done to keep it secured. You **really** need to convince the client to replace the machine. Anyone still running Server 2000 almost *deserves* to get hacked.

That out of the way, based on the system requirements listed on the [.Net 2.0 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16614) it looks like you can install .Net 2.0 sp1 on a Server 2000 machine with Service Pack 4. It ought to work in a basic sense, because this was supported once upon a time, even if it isn't any more.

ASP.Net made several significant changes in the transition from .Net 1.1 to .Net 2.0. It's hard to say how much work an update will be, but it's not likely to be easy. My advice would be to convince the client to get a *new server* to host the migrated project, with a new and *supported* version of Windows Server (2008 R2 at the *minimum*, if you want it *stay* supported for a significant length of time). This is consistent with the need to move away from Windows Server 2000. Copy the project as is to the new server, and do what needs to be done to get it working and *tested* there under a recent version of the .Net Framework... and for what it's worth, it's not likely to be a lot more work to go straight for .Net 4.0 than it is for 2.0 and bring the project all the way up to current practice.

This will let you do whatever you need to for development without impacting the production system, no matter how easy or difficult the upgrade turns out to be for you. When everything is ready, your development server will become the new production server. Re-point end users to the new server, possibly by changing a dns record or by re-naming the new machine with old name and IP and likely migrating some database information.

In short, while want you asked to do is *possible*, it is *seriously inadvisable*.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer first: Yes. IIS 5 will support .NET 2.

Hard answer second: The level of effort to upgrade a .NET 1.1 site to a .NET 2.0 site really depends on your site: the libraries referenced, the patterns used, etc so no one here can give you a good answer to that question. What I can say is that the upgrade to the .NET framework from 1.1 to 2.0 was a pretty major one. There are a lot of new things in 2.0 and I believe there was a decent amount that was also phased out. There is the possibility that many things can break on your site, but there is also the possibility that very few things (or even nothing!) on your site will break. The only way to find out is to do it.

If I were you, I would set up a test environment with .NET 2 and IIS 5 and just dump the site over as-is. Click around the site and see what works and what breaks.